# MetricsQL query based on values

Tags: metricsql

```json
[
  {
    "metric": {
      "__name__": "k8s_failure_value",
      "build": "90"
    },
    "values": [
      [
        1678924800,
        "0"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": {
      "__name__": "k8s_failure_value",
      "build": "91"
    },
    "values": [
      [
        1678924800,
        "1"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Can we search with respect to values? For example I want to get which values[0][1] is "1".

Answer (score 2):

> Can we search with respect to values? For example I want to get which values[0][1] is "1".

Sure! Just apply a comparison operator next to your metric selector like in the following example:

```
k8s_failure_value == 1
```

Read more about query language here https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#comparison-operations